# Adding text in three.js over some object

Tags: three.js

I am facing difficulty in adding text to my three.js script. I have searched a lot but  wherever i find a working model, it uses a previous version of three.js and thus i am not able to use it. Also textgeometry seems to not work. I wish to add 3d text and not 2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check three.js's official examples. There are many hints with latest three.js for you.

- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text
- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text_earcut
- http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text_pnltri

First, you need to load a font file with `new THREE.FontLoader`. The font file is supposed to be in JS file, like http://threejs.org/examples/fonts/optimer_bold.typeface.js. You can convert your font to JS with http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/

```
var font;
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( 'path/to/fontfile.js', function ( response ) {
    font = response;
} );
```

Then make a text geometry with `new THREE.TextGeometry` class using the font.

```
var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( text, {
    font: font,
    size: size,
    height: height,
    curveSegments: curveSegments,
    bevelThickness: bevelThickness,
    bevelSize: bevelSize,
    bevelEnabled: bevelEnabled,
    material: 0,
    extrudeMaterial: 1
});
```

Then, make a mesh

```
new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, material );
```

Comment: I am getting the following error on executing your method:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/prafful13/Documents/IITB/fonts/droid/droid_serif_regular.typeface.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.THREE.XHRLoader.load @ three.js:18280THREE.FontLoader.load @ three.js:18327(anonymous function) @ exp1.html:65
three.js:38590 THREE.TextGeometry: font parameter is not an instance of THREE.Font.THREE.TextGeometry @ three.js:38590(anonymous function) @ exp1.html:69

Comment: Because of the AJAX request. Try it on a local web server.